# Add passport auth only to a certain route group

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

How can i ge the following strategy to work?

I want to add the jwt auth strategy to all endpoints below `/api/v1/apiKeys`.

```
passport.use('jwtStrategy', new JwtStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true, jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), secretOrKey: process.env.APP_SECRET },
            (req: Request, payload, done) => {
                console.log('here');
                const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

                if (ip !== payload.ip) {
                    done(new Error("Invalid token"), false);
                } else {
                    req.headers["clientId"] = payload.clientId;
                    done(null, true);
                }
            }));

        router.use("/api/v1/apiKeys", passport.authenticate('jwtStrategy', { session: false }));

        router.post("/api/v1/apiKeys/generateApiKey",  async (req, res) => {
            const keyConfig = req.body;
            const { clientId } = <any>req.headers;
            const result = await ApiKeysServiceInstance.buildApiKey(clientId, keyConfig);
            res.json(result);
        });
```

With the current configuration, I always get a 401 response when trying 
to post at `/api/v1/apiKeys/generateApiKey`.

If I add the `passport.authenticate` method at level it works. Like this :

```
router.post("/api/v1/apiKeys/generateApiKey",  passport.authenticate('jwtStrategy', { session: false })), async (req, res) => {
    const keyConfig = req.body;
    const { clientId } = <any>req.headers;
    const result = await ApiKeysServiceInstance.buildApiKey(clientId, keyConfig);
    res.json(result);
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Habe you tried `router.all("/api/v1/apiKeys/*", pas.....`

Comment: I've tried that, no result